# Creating a chart with Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: extjs, charts, touch

I'm trying to add an chart to my Sencha Touch app.

I have added a view like this and inserted a chart how I saw it on a couple of sites:

```
Ext.define('dergraph.view.Graph', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'graph',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        layout: 'fit',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'chart',
                animate: true,
                store: 'dergraph.store.PhoneBook',
                legend: {
                    position: 'right'
                },

                axes: [{
                        type: 'Category',
                        fields: ['firstName'],
                        position: 'bottom', //x-axis
                        title: 'Category'
                    }, {
                        type: 'Numeric',
                        fields: ['value'],
                        position: 'left', //y-axis
                        title: 'Value'
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

But now I got in an Error in the Console of the browser: Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: axis.Category.

This is my require-part in the app.js:

```
requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.dataview.List',
        'Ext.chart.Chart',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Category'
],
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type`, `xtype`, etc. are case-sensitive, and the ones in the library are all lowercase.

So change `type: 'Category'` to `type: 'category'`, and `type: 'Numeric'` to `type: 'numeric'`, and your code will run.

You should also read the doc about [xtype](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-xtype). This option is used to indicate the type of component to create without having to use the `new` keyword yourself (allowing lazy initialization). The xtype option is only meaningful in the context of an object you want to *instantiate*, not one you *define*. So this line in your code has no effect:

```
xtype: 'graph',
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work now!

I used the xtype in main.js to view the site like this:
{
    xtype: 'graph'
    title: 'Graph',
    iconCls: 'compose'
}

Is it wrong?

Comment: To create a new xtype in Ext4 or Touch, you should use [alias](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-alias) in your definition: `alias: widget.graph`. Then, you can use, for example `Ext.widget({title: 'Graph', xtype: 'graph'})` or, as item, `Ext.widget({xtype: 'panel', items: [{xtype: 'graph'}]})`. Not sure that's very useful for the main view, though.

Answer (score 0):

did you include the Sencha Touch 2 Charts 2 Beta here? And if so, how exactly did you do that? Please start from the point after you downloaded it - I'm a rookie :)

Comment: It was my first project with Sencha, too. I only downloaded Sencha Touch. Nothing specific for Charts.

Comment: Really? Not even the full Sencha Touch Bundle which is only available paid or as a demo? Can someone clarify this? I thought charts is an additional package?!